# Can't connect to Play Store. Asks to sync app data instead

Tags: google-play-store

Device: Droid Razr Maxx

Every time I go to the Google Play store, a dialog box asks if I want to turn on background data. So I click enable, and it just brings up popup of a bunch of apps I have on my phone and whether or not I want to sync them. Then my phone gets all glitchy, like the background turns black and the drop down bar doesn't work. I don't understand why it just won't let me use the play store. What does syncing Facebook and Twitter have to do with downloading a game or an app?

I feel like the fix to this is simple, but I don't get it. My service has 4 or 5 bars 4G LTE, yet I can't download a little app.